# How can I determine whether a Delphi object is of a specific class and not any descendant class?

Tags: delphi, class-design

I have these classes and a procedure:

```
 TParent = class(TObject);
 TChild1 = class(TParent);     
 TChild2 = class(TParent);

 Procedure DoSomething(obj:TParent);
```

What I would like to do is when `obj` is a `TParent` and not a descendant raise an exception.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
if obj.classname = TParent.classname then raise exception.create....
```

but it seems a bit *hackish (TM)*

**More:** What i intended is to able to pass objects that shared properties/procedures in common. After more thought, the TParent Object isn't really needed at all, what i needed was an interface object shown in my answer.

Comment: Appart from the answers already given, there certainly are valid cases to want this but not that many. Why do you need to know?

Comment: +1 for thinking that was a hack. As a rule of thumb, if you're doing type-related things with *strings*, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ive solved what i was trying to do, It hit me on the head last night.

```
iParentInterface = interface(IUnknown);
TChild1 = class(TInterfacedObject,iParentInterface);     
TChild2 = class(TInterfacedObject,iParentInterface);   

Procedure DoSomething(obj:iParentInterface);
```

Answer (score 40):

You'll probably find the following `TObject` class methods useful:

- [ClassType](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TObject__ClassType.html) - returns the class of an object
- [ClassParent](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TObject__ClassParent.html) - gives the parent class of the class
- [InheritsFrom](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__TObject__InheritsFrom.html) - returns if a class inherits from another class (ie, checks the entire inheritance chain).  It includes the current class.

So, you could achieve what you want (descends from TParent but not TDescendant?) with something like the following code (untested, don't have Delphi at this moment):

```
if obj.ClassType.InheritsFrom(TParent)
  and not obj.ClassType.InheritsFrom(TDescendant) then...
```

Or, if I've misunderstood and you just want to see if an object is a TParent, and not any kind of descendant at all, try:

```
if obj.ClassType = TParent then...
```

Delphi was way ahead of its time by providing access to classes via [metaclasses](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_TClass.html), so rather than just checking the class name you can access an actual class object.

Comment: Ahead of its time maybe, but still trailing way behind Smalltalk!

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to add a Smalltalk comment in my answer :)

Answer (score 17):

You're on the right track, but instead of comparing classnames, it would be simpler to check the `ClassType` property.

```
if obj.ClassType = TParent then raise exception.create....
```

Comment: Not only simpler, but also *more correct*. It's possible for two classes to have the same name but not be the same class. (The `ClassName` function doesn't include the unit name, which would otherwise distinguish like-named classes. Not sure what it does about nested classes.)

Comment: @Rob It does the obvious: 'TOuter.TInner'.

Comment: Documentation says that the keyword *is* should be used instead of comparing by ClassType.

Comment: @jmiller: The **is** keyword and comparing `ClassType` do two different things.  Most of the time, you want to check if an object is assignment-compatible with a specific class, and **is** will do that.  But in this particular case, that's not what the OP is looking for, and comparing `ClassType` is.

Answer (score 13):

Good practice in object-oriented programming states that this should not be done.  What you are describing is a direct violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which states that:

> objects in a program should be
>   replaceable with instances of their
>   subtypes without altering the
>   correctness of that program

I think you should explain what problem you are attempting to solve and then a better approach might become apparent.

Comment: This was the nudge that i needed,

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: Introduce an abstract method in TParent, say *CheckValidChild*, and override it in the descendant classes. Now when you call *obj.CheckValidChild* you get an *EAbstractError* if the instance of obj is of class TParent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reserved word (IS) to check whether a instance is a type or a child of a type.

Example:

```
TFruit = class
end;
TApple = class(TFruit)
end;
TOrange = class(TFruit)
end;

procedure check;
var 
   a: TApple;
   b: TOrange;
begin
   if (a is TFruit) then showmessage('a is a fruit');
   if (b is TFruit) then showmessage('b is also a fruit');
end;
```